# How to embed image in SharePoint Workflow Association Form?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, sharepoint, embedded-resource, sharepoint-workflow

I am developing a custom SharePoint workflow in Visual Studio. I have a custom association form (ASPX) and I'd like to display an image, which is embedded into the project (and subsequently wsp).

I've tried all the standard Visual Studio methods for embedding an image in my SharePoint workflow project, but when trying to set the ImageUrl on asp:Image, the resource picker never shows my resource regardless of how I attempt to embed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question, whilst looking to implement the suggestion made by moontear...

Right click on the project > Add > 'SharePoint "Images' Mapped Folder', this creates a 'system' directory within the project where you can import your image resources.

These are then selectable using the resource explorer (which comes up when trying to set a field like ImageUrl).

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to embed the image as a resource? You normally wouldn't do that in SharePoint.

Add a Module to your Visual Studio project and add the image in there. Afterwards you can just set the ImageUrl to the relative Url where you deploy your module to (e.g. SiteAssets).

Comment: Thank you for your response. When attempting to add the 'Module' i stumbled across the solution detailed in my answer. Cheers.